# Custom Permissions without changing views but add items

Tags: list, permissions, calendar, overlay

I have an .aspx page that is made up of different webparts (calendar, links, and discussion).  The calendar is made up of five overlays coming from different lists, where the manager adds deadlines.  The individual is not able to see others events because of the filtering.

With that being said I do want them to be able to view, add, and edit their own created events on the "main calendar".  From the list of permission below which would give me this ability:

[image]

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. You need to make sure each person / SP group has the following: Add Items, Edit Items, Delete Items, View Items. Now keep this in mind, this doesn't prevent them from accessing someone else's content using a different view or going to item directly. You need item-level permissions to be sure only the creator has access to their items.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was a way to remove the ability to cycle through different views.

Comment: Afraid not. You'd need to create custom application pages if you need more granular rights.